# Input return key in an SQL script

Tags: shell-script, sql

I have an SQL script which when run prompts me to input a value. If I don't input any value and press the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> key, it will select the default value and will pull all the records. I am trying to incorporate this into a shell script where I don't want the script to prompt me for any value and should just accept the "return key" by default. Is there a way I can do this ?

Example of what I'm trying to do.

`in_code` is the variable in the `xecute.sql`, which accepts a value. I want this variable to select the <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> key by default. The code I use below doesn't work.

```
#! /bin/bash
sqlplus -s xxx/xxx<<!
define in_code='echo -e "\n"'
@execute.sql
exit
!
```

Comment: Any help please ?? Tried multiple areas and none seem to be working

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the relevant bits of the SQL? I'm not familiar with `sqlplus` but seeing a bit of what the SQL is doing (reading a value, for example) might help.

Comment: I am also not familiar with how sqlplus reads its input, but does it work if you put a blank line after the part of the SQL code that's expecting input? Or define in_code to be single-quote (hit enter here), single-quote?